# How to conditionally use existing resource in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In my Terraform (0.14.10) module, I'd like to provide the option of deploying into an existing AWS VPC. I'm varying the count operator based on a boolean input `use_existing_network`.

If `use_existing_network` is false, I create a VPC network. If it's true, I retrieve the existing resource with a `data` block.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "cluster_network" {
  count = var.use_existing_network ? 0 : 1

  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = var.network_name
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "cluster_network" {
  count = var.use_existing_network ? 1 : 0

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.network_name]
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error when I attempt to reference the network (a tuple, since it's created with the count operator) later:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on ../../modules/network/main.tf line 61, in resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw":
  61:   vpc_id = aws_vpc.cluster_network[0].id
    |----------------
    | aws_vpc.cluster_network is empty tuple

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Why doesn't this work, and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `cluster_network` is either a resource or data source, depending on the condition. They are referred to differently. You could use local to unify that. For example with [try](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/try.html):

```
locals {
   cluster_network = try(aws_vpc.cluster_network[0], data.aws_vpc.cluster_network[0])
}
```

Then use `local.cluster_network.id` in the rest of the code.